# CCDN Forum Bundle and FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to configure CCDN forum bundle to use FOSUserBundle roles but i can't accomplish desired behaviour changing my security.yml.
Official documentation doesn't help either.

Anyway, every user regardless of role can delete and edit other peoples posts etc. I'd like that only ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN can do that and others just to read, edit and delete their own posts.

Does anyone know how to configure roles such as moderator, user or admin in CCDNForumBundle?

I have:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_PREMIUM:     ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_MODERATOR, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
```

Comment: What problem do you have? What error?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: What roles have user and what controller you want to use? Where is related code?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration only user with `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` is allowed to change any posts. If you want to allow eg. `ROLE_PREMIUM` you can set it like this:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_PREMIUM:     [ROLE_USER, ROLE_MODERATOR]
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_PREMIUM
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
```

Now `ROLE_PREMIUM` can modify any posts in forum, `ROLE_ADMIN` have the same privileges as `ROLE_PREMIUM`, so he can also modify all posts, the same with `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN`.

More info: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles

Comment: This isn't going to help with the requirement of being able to edit its own posts.

Comment: Sorry, but that's should be default behaviour, user cannot edit other authors posts. Are you sure you check it correctly? Eg. From user only with ROLE_USER?

Comment: I tried it with no luck. When i try to access forum with ROLE_USER i get permission exception. I can only get in with ROLE_ADMIN

Comment: I fixed it by adding role user to permission list of a forum. I thought it will be the default behaviour. But now when i dump authorizedToRead variable i get only ROLE_ADMIN. My users can access forum but can't read it. I really don't get it.